# How can I find the device on google debugview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I can find my physical device on adb device list using code "adb devices" and then:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.play.myapp
```

but Firebase debugview still show no available device.
I can't find any helpful documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Revoke from developer options and refresh the tab. If still not showed up try connecting other device as sometime it would happens and I always connect another device.